# ADB No Devices Found

Tags: android, adb

I am attempting to install an [Android](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29) app on my brand new [Nexus 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nexus_10). I have a .apk file. I have downloaded the Android SDK, installed "Android SDK Tools", "Android SDK Platform-tools", and Google USB Driver. I have checked the setting on my Nexus 10 for "Unknown Sources".

When I run "adb devices" from the command terminal, it doesn't list any devices. I attempted to follow [this recommendation](http://blog.fh-kaernten.at/wehr/?p=1182), because it was identical to a suggestion I had previously found here on Stack Overflow. After following those steps, "adb devices" still returns an empty list and to make it worse, when I connect my Nexus 10 to my PC, Windows doesn't show any folders within the device.

I have undone the steps in that link, along with everything else I have done so far, as well as uninstalling my Nexus 10 from [Device Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_Manager) and reinstalling it, but I am still not seeing any folders in the device.

Is there anything I am missing to get my device to show up in ADB devices?

What can I do to get Windows to see the folders within the device?

Comment: Have you enabled usb debugging in the developer settings on your nexus 10?

Comment: A note to others:  The SDK will not install the driver at all!  The driver doesn't even have an installer actually.  You have to plug in a device and manually tell windows where the driver is.

Comment: The developer settings are hidden in more recent versions of Abdroid.See http://www.askvg.com/tip-enable-hidden-secret-developer-options-menu-in-google-android-mobiles-phones-and-tablets/. Summary, go to Settings -> About Phone -> Build Number, and tap on it 7 times to make the developer settings visible. Seriously. My phone is Android 4.4.2, and it worked for me.

Answer (score 211):

Windows 8 wouldn't recognize my Nexus 10 device. Fixed by Setting the transfer mode to Camera (PTP) through the settings dialogue on the device.

Settings > Storage > Menu > USB Computer connection to "Camera (PTP)"

Comment: This fixed my issue, the USB Computer connection is a bit hidden , you have to click on the 3 dots menu ..

Comment: If you don't have the "USB Computer connection" option (common [problem](http://en.miui.com/thread-15786-1-1.html) for MIUI users), create a custom shortcut to package : `com.android.settings`, class : `com.android.settings.UsbSettings` (be careful!), using QuickShortcutMaker, for example.

Comment: I had the same problem on a LG G3 Device that was not getting detected on a Mac. Selecting PTP mode fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: In Android M/6.0, this is now found under - Settings > Developer Options > Select USB Configuration

Comment: In my case (Android 8): Developer options > Networking > Select USB configuration

Answer (score 135):

**For Windows 8 users:**

After trying every solution given here, with no success, I found this:

Go to *Device Manager*

[image: Update Driver Software ...]

---

*Browse my computer for drivers* -> *Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer*

Choose *Android Device* and then *Android ADB Interface*.

[image: Android ADB Interface]

---

Now I have my devices listed at `adb devices`.

Comment: I found the follow guide helpful.  Walks you through step by step for doing this...http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/android/usbdebug/manualinstall.php

Comment: This worked on my Blu Studio X device, which was working fine in Windows 10 until I upgraded it to Lollipop (5.x)

Comment: Nice job. Want to add... on windows the drivers are located at : "android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver"

Comment: This solved the problem for me as well on Windows 10 Pro with a Nexus 5X. I had installed drivers already via Android SDK Manager (didn't suffice) and picked the directory [...]\android-sdk\extras in the driver install wizard, afterwards the device showed up. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me, but only after going into Android SDK manager, manually selecting to install Extras -> USB driver, and then back in the device manager's "Update driver" dialog, selecting "Pick from a list of drivers" -> "All devices" -> "Have disk" -> point to location of the USB driver, which in my case was under C:\Users\<userid>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver. Note that AppData is a hidden directory. I also had to confirm that I really want to install this driver although Windows claimed it wasn't compatible. But it works. Phew, quite bizarre process...

Comment: Thanks, worked. I had to actually to uninstall the android device driver inside "Device Manager", unplug the tablet, replug it back in, then do your steps. For some reason, this step didn't work before re-plugging in the tablet again

Answer (score 69):

This situation seems to arise with some ADB drivers. I have encountered the same thing with a couple of Google devices and installing the [Universal ADB windows driver](https://adb.clockworkmod.com/) has fixed it for me every time.

Comment: Instead of using that driver, a more reliable one is the Google Driver: http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html

Comment: @phyrox The questioner had already tried that driver, and I confirmed at the time that it did not fix the issue, whereas the driver I mentioned does. It is conceivable that google has fixed the issue for that phone since my answer was posted (I can no longer test to see if this is the case), in which case I agree that the google driver may be a better choice. But if not, my answer is the only reliable way to fix the issue.

Comment: This did not work for me. I still get an empty list from adb devices. :( Could it be that I'm missing a step? Also, am I right in assuming that adb devices will not list the device if I haven't enabled USB debugging on the phone?

Answer (score 65):

Use another **cable**.

Just found out that one of my regular charging cables had Vcc, Gnd pairs, but no Data+, Data-.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Pinouts

Comment: pay attention also to USB hubs: sometimes the problem is not on the cable itself but on the power supplied to Vcc, so it may happen that too many devices connected to the same USB hub may cause `adb` to lose connection. Connecting the device directly to the computer may solve the issue in this case.

Comment: Tip: Try a third cable if the second one didn't work. Worked for me. Cables that came with Android phones didn't work.

Comment: There are charging-only cables and all-purpose ones.  The best I've found come from monoprice.com and some even have lifetime warranty.  Prices are reasonable (~$2).  Get a few and keep them around.

Comment: Cables decay in time. The more you jiggle it around and tug on it, the faster the metal fatigue kicks in.

Answer (score 52):

Make sure to **Enable USB debugging** in *Settings* -> *Developer options*

Also, run "adb devices" after getting into the platform tools folder in the Android SDK (unless you have that folder on your system path already), otherwise the command won't be found.

Comment: If nothing works, try changing the usb cord. I used a different one and it worked immediately. haha

Answer (score 51):

The device may not be visible for debugging if it is in MTP mode. Some devices only work in PTP mode (or even in "charging only" mode).

This can be changed in *Settings* > *Developer Options* > *Networking* > *Default USB configuration* > *PTP*.

Also, you'll get a notification on your android device asking you for confirmation about USB configuration setting change and to allow it.

Note: You can turn on **developer options** by following the link below: 
[enable developer options](https://www.howtogeek.com/129728/how-to-access-the-developer-options-menu-and-enable-usb-debugging-on-android-4.2/)

Comment: That worked like a charm. @rds you are right. Changing the USB connection mode does the trick of reinstalling all the drivers in the Camera(PTP) mode and Voila! The Debug Key Dialogue appeared! Or in some cases one can try Checking/Un-checking the **Allow Debugging checkbox** in developer settings as well.

Comment: For me I had to switch away from MTP to "Audio Source" mode in "Select USB Configuration" in the developer options.  Charging Only mode did not work for me.

Comment: In my case (Android 8): Developer options > Networking > Select USB configuration

Comment: This helped, I was having issues on my laptop with Android studio 4.1.1 to get Pico VR headsets to show up. Changing it to MIDI, Charging or Audio source all work. PTP & MTP both don't seem to work as of writing this.

Comment: in my case I had no *PTP* option, so I had set it to "Transfer files". btw it's Android 10

Answer (score 44):

I have found a solution (for Windows 7):

1. Connect your Nexus 10 to PC
2. Go to Windows Device Manager
3. RClick on ADB Interface  -> properties
4. Details -> Hardware Ids.

You will see two records like these:

> **USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE2**
>   **USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE2&MI_01**

5 Open the android_winusb.inf file (I have it in "`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver" directory`)

6 Create such records in [Google.NTx86] and [Google.NTamd64] sections using Hardware Ids from properties of ADB interface:

> ;Google Nexus 10
>   %SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, **USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE2**
>   %CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, **USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE2&MI_01**

7 Save the file, and update driver for ADB Interface with showing the path to "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver" directory

Comment: Remember to do this with Administrator access, otherwise you won't be able to save file.

Comment: Sorry @bluesm, but I can't. I found this solution with help of intuition and user experience.

Comment: Doing this steps made the windows not allow the update of driver because of checksum failure.

Comment: I think I'm having the same problem @petrumo mentioned - I'm on a Windows 8 machine, and it worked fine up until step 7 (Update Driver Software) at which point it complained "The hash for the file is not present in the specified catalog file. The file is likely corrupt or the victim of tampering."

Comment: for me the solution was to uninstall from SDK Manager the Google USB Driver, reinstall it and update the driver without modifying it's properties.

Comment: @bluesm, each device presents itself to the operating system using "magic" numbers like the ones found in step 4. Windows looks for these magic numbers in the "inf" file and, if found, proceeds with installation of whatever drivers the "inf" file points out. I don't know WHY the numbers for Nexus 10 would be missing though. (I tried reinstalling the Google USB Driver, didn't work for me.)

Comment: @bluesm, VID = vendor id (assigned by USB, 18d1 for Google), PID = product id (assigned by Google)

Answer (score 35):

Sometimes ADB loses connection to the device, and needs to be reset.  If you have everything else working (ie USB driver installed, Developer settings enabled on the device), and still can't see your device, you need to reset the ADB process.

This is available in the DDMS Perspective (from within Eclipse), Devices tab (the triangle on the far right includes a menu item to perform the reset).

Otherwise from the command line, you can reset it with the following 2 commands:

```
adb kill-server
```

then

```
adb start-server
```

Comment: Hi,I tried the adb kill-server and start-server .But still its not showing up

Comment: You need to add the adb command from your classpath (or execute it directly from the location where it is on your filesystem).

Comment: FWIW, I was having issues after starting `adb` under WSL, and killing the WSL instance using this command seems to have let me use the Windows version of `adb` (I guess when one takes port `:5037`, the other side assumes it's already running).

Answer (score 15):

Enable Developer options in your device. To enable the developer mode, `setting->About phone`, tap Build number option 8 times continuously

Go to `Settings-> Developer options` and Turn on USB debugging

From the above steps it didn't work try this step, Go to `Settings->Security` and turn on `Allow Unknown Resources`

Answer (score 10):

You have to download the drivers from the SDK manager (extras → Google USB Driver)

Then you have to install the USB driver in Windows (it works for me in Windows 8.1):

(Copy and paste from http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#InstallingDriver:)

1. Connect your Android-powered device to your computer's USB port.
2. Right-click on "Computer" from your desktop or Windows Explorer, and select "Manage".
3. Select "Devices" in the left pane.
4. Locate and expand "Other device" in the right pane.
5. Right-click the device name (such as Nexus S) and select "Update Driver Software." This will launch the "Hardware Update Wizard".
6. Select "Browse my computer for driver software" and click "Next."
   Click "Browse" and locate the USB driver folder. (The Google USB Driver is located in `<sdk>\extras\google\usb_driver\`.)
7. Click "Next" to install the driver.

Answer (score 7):

After downloading the Google drivers via Android SDK Manager (available via Eclipse, Intellij or Android Studio), I had to update the driver in Computer Management > Device Manager > Other Devices > ADB - right clicking and clicking on update driver and browsing for updated driver finally did the trick.

BTW, a total nightmare for me as well. I continue to be bewildered that setting up a dev environment should be the most difficult task imaginable, with each new inexplicable failure leading to another one. Jeesh! Good luck.

Answer (score 6):

I still get this once in a while and it usually works if I unplug it and plug it back in a different port.  I'm on Linux but had the same thing happen on Windows before.

Answer (score 5):

On my Windows 8.1 64bit (Nexus 5 did not show up), only manually installing the USB driver fixed it:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html
The "Google USB Driver" in "Android SDK Manager" was installed already.

Answer (score 4):

Installing [Samsung Kies](http://www.samsung.com/us/kies/) and using their tool to reinstall device drivers,   is what finally worked for me with my Galaxy S3 and Tab S 8.4

Comment: reinstalling device drivers worked for me (samsung galaxy ace 4) :)

Comment: In this case Samsung USB driver for mobile phones will do the job.

Comment: In my case the ADB Composite or Android Device phone were not listed in the Windows Device Manager, the Phone was listed under Portable Device. The solution was I had to download the USB Driver from the Phone Manufacturer such as Samsung. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Normally SDB will download the driver in the **android-sdk-windows\extras\google\usb_driver** path

Here are the steps that worked for me:

1. Enable USB debugging.
2. Do to device manager, right click on ADB device and click update driver software.
3. Select "Browse my computer for Driver Software"
4. Select "Let me pick from list of Device drivers on my computer"
5. Click on "Have Disk" option.
6. Select the driver path **android-sdk-windows\extras\google\usb_driver** (path of sdk)
   7.Select 1st driver out of list of drivers shown.

And hopefully, it will work.

Comment: I don't have "ADB device" in my Device Manager

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I recommend you *DO NOT* run ADB under VirtualBox if you are using a Windows Host. Somehow I got VirtualBox to lock the device drivers on the host, eventually making it so that the ADB wouldn't work on the client nor the host for any device I plugged in. To fix, I removed VirtualBox extensions on the host and ran http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html to delete the incorrect drivers. I could not get the correct drivers to load while VirtualBox extensions were installed, and this problem was a complete bastard to diagnose and fix.

Edit 2: Also the following is probably out of date, now that Google have released an integrated ADB extension for Chrome.

What an installation nightmare... Here are the steps I needed to get my Nexus 10 recognised on an XP virtual machine running under VirtualBox:

- If you get asked to install Nexus 10 drivers, make sure to untick "don't ask again" (you *WANT* to be asked again!).
- Plug in the Nexus 10 USB connection
- Turn on debugging in the Nexus 10 settings Developer menu (tap "About Tablet" 7 times to get that menu).
- In your virtual machine settings (host), add the samsung Nexus 10 device to the USB Device Filters (important - selecting it from the devices menu didn't seem to work).
- In guest install java jre (if you don't have java installed). In Control Panel, change Java settings so that java doesn't run in the browser (to help prevent security issues).
- In guest get the adk zip file and put it somewhere permanent. I needed to delete the .android config directory from the user directory because I moved the directory.
- Run the SDK Manager.exe - if it doesn't work, try running sdk\tools\android.bat which seems to give better error reporting.
- From SDK Manager install the Google USB driver package.
- Unplug the Nexus 10 and plug it in again, and install the Google USB driver package.
- Restart the guest.
- running c:>[...]\sdk\platformtools> `adb devices` finally shows me the device...

Answer (score 2):

For the Blu Studio 5.5s ADB drivers, you have to go through this hoop.  I am certain it is the same with all Blu phones or maybe for all non-Google mfg phones, I am not sure.    First of all if you connect the Blu device with USB cable and USB Debuggin off, you will see that Windows 7 loads a generic driver for you to copy on/off files to the phone and SD storage.   This will appear when the USB cable is first plugged in and appears as a device icon under Control Panel, Device Manager, Portable Devices, BLU STUDIO 5.5 S (or the device you are working with).   Do not bother getting the hardware ID yet - just observe that this happens (which indicates you are good so far and don't have a bad cable or something).

Go to the phone and switch on USB Debugging in the Developer section of your phone.   Notice that an additional item appears as an undefined device now in the device manager list, it will have the yellow exclamation mark and it may have the same name of the phone listed as you saw under Portable Devices.  Ignore this item for the moment.   Now, without doing anything to the phone (it should be already in USB debug mode) go back to the Portable Devices in Device Manager and right-click the BLU STUDIO 5.5 S or whatever phone you are working with that is listed there **without the exclamation mark** (listed under Portable Devices).  Right click on the icon under Portable Devices, in this example the name that appears is BLU STUDIO 5.5 S.  On that icon select Properties, Details, and under the pull down, select Hardware IDs and copy down what you see.

For BLU STUDIO 5.5 S I get:

```
USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0C02&REV_0216&MI_00
USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0C02&MI_00
```

(Note if you do this out of turn, the HW ID will be different with the phone USB debugging turned off.  You want to copy the value that it changes to when the USB debugging is ON)

Now do as the instructions say above, of course customizing the lines you add the the INF file with those relating to your own phone, not the Nexus 10.   Here is what to customize; when you downloaded the SDK you should have a file structure expanded from the ZIP such as this:

```
\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver
```

Find the file named: `android_winusb.inf` in the usb_driver folder
Make a copy of it and name it anything, such as myname.inf
Edit the myname.inf and add the lines as instructed above only modified for your particular phone.   For example, for the BLU STUDIO 5.5 S, I added the following 2 lines as instructed in the 2 locations as instructed.

```
;BLU STUDIO 5.5 S
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0C02&REV_0216&MI_00
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0C02&MI_00
```

Note that you add these lines to both the 32 and 64 bit sections, matching how the example in the tutorial reads.

Now go back up to the unknown device that appeared in Device Manager when you switched on device USB  debugging and right click on this item (has yellow exclamation mark), right click on it and then select Update Driver Software, and then Browse My Computer, Let Me Pick, click on the Have Disk button and browse to find the myname.inf.   Continue to agree to all the prompts warning you it might not be the right driver.   As the final step, Windows should have identified the device as Android ADB Interface and once that is done, you should be able to go back, open your CMD window and run the command "adb devices" as instructed in this tutorial and now you should see that the phone is now discovered and communicating.

Now you can go have fun with the adb command.

Answer (score 2):

At first Thanks [@rmsyk's post](https://reameizu.com/adb-shell-to-meizu-cellphone/).

For my issue and after long time suffering with ***Meizu C9 Pro*** witch require just android ADB drivers (no special drivers) referring to manufacturer and it solved in my Windows 7 PC by the bellow steps.

1. Make Sure to

   - Install latest version of ADB & Fastboot with the needed drivers.
   - Enable Developer options & USB Debugging.
   - Enable Media File Transfer (MTP Mode).
2. **Manually replace** `C:\Users\USERNAME\.android` **with the folder included** [**here**](https://mega.nz/#!sglBgD6Y!0CzbEIQ9MscSN8B-1ZxqO9APw58ga-6TigYFChS2TSg) **,Then kill process 'adb.exe' if found from Windows Task Manager and use** `adb devices` **and finally my device listed successfully and just confirm the PC as trusted.**

Notes:

1. Android Studio was uninstalled in earlier time and also i tried to reinstall but was not a solution at all.
2. Tried `adb kill-server` & `adb start-server` but was not a solution too.

Answer (score 2):

As well as the usual settings (enable USB debugging) I also had to select `Enable OEM unlock` in the Developer options.

This supposedly makes the device less secure, but it's your device and you know what you want to do.

Once checked the device behaved as expected and appears in the `adb devices` list.

You can always reverse all these settings once you're finished.

Answer (score 2):

I was using a Samsung phone with Android 10. It was detecting earlier but stopped detecting on Windows 10 after I **factory data reset** the Android 10 phone. Though It was normally detected on Windows 11 PC.

When I dig a little deeper, in android phone settings inside developer options there is a configuration named **Default USB Configuration** [Settings -> Developer Options -> Default USB Configuration]. When I select that option, There were several options that came and none of them was selected by default.

I tried selecting one option after the other and when I selected the **USB Tethering** option; than android device started detecting.

Answer (score 1):

Confirm you have the correct platform SDK tools

For Windows 10, had to manually download the latest platform SDK tools from Android as the version supplied through Visual Studio 2017 EMDK for Xamarin was not sufficient. Everything else except `adb.exe devices` worked.

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools

After the platform tools were manually downloaded, device showed up regardless of USB configuration (charging, MTP, etc.)

Installing an emulator device at this stage is also helpful to see whether the problem is with adb or your physical device.

```
List of devices attached
12345D1234      device
emulator-5554   device
```

Answer (score 1):

There could be two reasons why `adb devices` command is not working for you. Either your phones USB drivers are not installed properly or you have not enabled USB debugging mode.

I created a tool that makes installing USB drivers a one click thing.

1. Just connect your phone in USB debugging mode to PC.
2. Run my [tool](https://github.com/fawazahmed0/Latest-adb-fastboot-installer-for-windows)

It will detect and install drivers specific to your phone and also install the latest ADB & Fastboot binaries with it.

The tool is available at my [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/fawazahmed0/Latest-adb-fastboot-installer-for-windows)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Windows 8. The [Android](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29)/[SDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_kit) [USB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB) driver was installed correctly, but I forgot to install the USB driver from my phone. After installing the phone USB driver [ADB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Debug_Bridge) works fine.

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

It's so easy, just turn off your Android device, and then hold down both "Volume Down" key and "Power" at the same time. Wait a few seconds till it start in recovery mode, done.
Now type `adb devices`, and you'll see your device.

Comment: see obi4niy's answer, http://stackoverflow.com/a/17186551/2855059
that's the solution.
and btw. Volume Down + power is used to take a screenshot when the phone is on not off,

Answer (score 0):

I have a Motorola Razr and I was having trouble identifying my device. 
What I did was:

1 - From the command prompt (as an administrator) -> `adb kill-servers`

2 - Downloaded Motorola Device Manager here -> https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/88481

3 - I waited until the installation was complete.

4 - From the command prompt (as an administrator) -> `adb devices`

Comment: Only this answer solved my problem of adb under Windows 7 not finding my Motorola Moto E2.  Prior to that I tried killing adb, switching phone from MTP to PDP, reinstalling the native Windows driver, and installing Intel and "Universal" USB driver packages.  In the words of Koushik Dutta, _for whatever reason, every phone manufacturer has their own adb driver_.  Without the Motorola driver installed, Windows 7 saw the phone as a USB media device, but adb didn't.  Windows Device Manager now shows my E2 as _Motorola ADB Interface_; before it showed it as an "ADB Interface" w/no device driver.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on debugging in the Nexus settings Developer menu (tap "About Tablet" 7 times to get that menu).

Freaking Google tricks!

Comment: Google easter eggs! find some [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Google_hoaxes_and_easter_eggs)

Answer (score 0):

Have you had an android update recently? I updated to Lollipop and all the sudden I had no adb devices. Boo! I spent awhile trying a few things to no avail. Then I went into my developer options and lo and behold, "USB debugging" had been turned off. Silly Google. After turning it back on, it immediately showed up and I'm back in business!

Answer (score 0):

GoTo DeviceManager, then right click on the android device and click uninstall driver.
Unplug and plug the device back...then a pop will come on your device while your pc installs the required drivers. Click "allow" on the popup.
You can see your device when you type "adb devices" in command prompt.

Comment: What DeviceManager are you referring to?

Comment: I think he's referring to the Windows "Device Manager" control panel.  It's a good suggestion, for someone who has an old/broken driver installed.  +1

Answer (score 0):

For Windows,  just end all the processes related to Blue stacks or any such emulator if you are using.

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**To have ADB in MTP mode**

If you don't find any ADB device (nothing with exclamation mark) in the device manager (with all developers settings on phone checked), do this:

In Device Manager :

UpdateDriver->Manuel Install->Search on my computer->Select from installed driver list -> then select the one with the word usb in it (not MTP).

Edit: after that, you'll then have 2 or 3 peripheral, one for USB and one for ADB, install adb driver using usual method (see first answers)

Comment: Just a duplicate of one of the top answers.

Comment: Which one... ? I don't think you understood my title/first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

There's obviously a ton of different problems that could be causing this (and a ton of different solutions to go along with those problems). So think about all the solutions!

If you've gotten this phone and computer pair to work together before, but they aren't working any more, it might be a **specific program on your computer** rather than a problem on your phone. Some programs install/use their own adb, and only one of these can connect to your phone at a time. I think this makes a race condition, so sometimes it'll connect fine.

Some programs that run adb:

HTC Sync Manager - uninstall this.

`chrome://inspect` - lets you view localhost on your phone. Just close the window when you're done with it.

Comment: after I use chrome://inspect and close the window, I need to reboot the device for it to be seen again by adb and AndroidStudio.

Answer (score 0):

For my Nexus 6P downloading drivers from Google helped resolved the issue. Here is the [URL](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb.html) with documentation. And [here](https://dl-ssl.google.com//android/repository/latest_usb_driver_windows.zip) you can download the driver itself.

P.S. I saw some people advice to download some drivers from random places on internet. While this might help it's too dangerous in my mind to download unknown drivers from unofficial places. So the one from Google worked well for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Also in android studio you can via the SDK manager install the google USB drivers and you' should be set after this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have enabled Developer Options and USB Debugging for a Nexus, the win-usb supposedly works.

One tell-tale sign whether your driver is right is if it's got ADB in the name in Device Manager.

For my Galaxy line, I had a driver installed, but it wasn't the ADB driver.

For many non-Nexus Androids, the win-usb driver will not work. Instead, you will need to install one of the OEM drivers: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html

This finally got me an ADB compatible driver, and after switching to PTP adb finally was able to find my device.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for my case.

1. Go to **Tools->Layout Inspector**.
2. Press **Restart** button a few times.

I have no idea how it connect with **ADB** but it works.

Answer (score 0):

#### Easy way to install ADB drivers

I always use [ADB Driver Installer](http://adbdriver.com/) for installing adb drivers for any mobile. You only need to click on **Install** button. and all set!

[image]

If your device is not listed here, then you can check enable your [developer setting](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options), check your USB cable.

Answer (score 0):

If you're at all familiar with Linux use that instead of Windows.  On a Raspberry Pi, do

```
apt-get install android-tools-adb andoid-tools-fastboot
```

There are no special USB drivers needed, it just works.  Android is based on Linux so you're working more in native mode.  Many of the problems I see here are Windows problems.  osx may have advantages over Windows here too.  Adb and fastboot both have man (manual) pages which are accessible from Linux.

Original question: I see no devices in adb when the phone's in fastboot mode, adb and fastboot seem to be mutually exclusive, you can only use one or the other at a time.  USB debugging has to be on.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a new addition to the check-list.

Check that your anti-virus has not blocked/vaulted the adb.exe in platform-tools directory.If you cant find the adb.exe in the SDK "platform-tools" directory, then its likely that it has.

C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe

I use AVG, and it had vaulte dit because it thought it was an IDP.Generic virus.
You can add it as an exception to allow it to run, and restore it from the vault.

My symptoms were that android-studio "tools"->Connection Assistant would recognize the usb-device in the list, but an adp restart button would remain grey. As it couldn't find the exe, but it didnt complain, just hung.

Its only when i manually tried to bounce the adp process via the command line , that I saw the adp.exe was missing.

Hopefully this will save someone else a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

problem : device is not appearing in vscode and ABD interface - no driver found

Solution:

1. Enable USB debugging in mobile.
2. Connect your mobile and laptop using USB cable
3. go to https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb click on the "Click here to download the Google USB Driver ZIP file (ZIP)"
4. go to device manager -> other devices -> right click on ADB device and click update driver software.
   Select "Browse my computer for Driver Software"
   Select "Let me pick from list of Device drivers on my computer"
   double click "show all devices"
   Click on "Have Disk" option.
   Select the driver path **android-sdk-windows\extras\google\usb_driver** .Select android_winusb.inf file
   select Android ADB interface -> click next
   Click Yes to install, close the window upon success.

   Now you will see the device appearing in VSCODE.

Answer (score 0):

Every time this happens to me I need to go into Developer Options on my  G6 and set the USB Configuration as "midi"

Answer (score 0):

If USB Debugging is already enabled but `adb devices` is hanging, or not responding, try going into the developer settings on the Andriod device, disabling USB Debugging, and then re-enabling it again.

This process can sometimes help a (Windows or other) machine to pick up `adb` commands again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is something wrong with your usb cable, change a usb cable and try.

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to device manager and check hardware id's.
2. Check if the `usb.inf` file has the device listed in it
3. If not, add the device hardware id and install it from the device manager.