# Where is InstallDebug in Gradle? How to install a test Android App?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio

I'm trying to install an Android app I'm developing in Android Studio on my test device. I normally do this with the Gradle task called "InstallDebug. In my newly created project however, I now don't see this task in my list of Gradle Tasks anymore. The only two things I see starting with Install* are

- installDefaultFlavorDebug
- installDefaultFlavorTest

Does anybody know which Gradle Task I need to use to install my app on my phone to test it?

Comment: is there a reason why you don't install the debug version of your app by IDE?

Comment: @owe - I'm not sure what you mean. The problem I have is that I normally simply click Gradle on the left, and select InstallDebug from the list of available Gradle Tasks. But in my current project, the installDebug option is not listed in the list of Gradle Tasks..

Comment: I don't know if we talk about the same thing, but you also could just choose the right `BuildVariant` and `Run` your configuration.

Answer (score 4):

Now you will find this tasks:

```
gradlew install<Flavor><Build Type>.
```

Example: 2 flavors `f1,f2`, and 2 build types `debug, release`.

You will find:

```
installF1Debug - Installs the Debug build for flavor f1
installF1DebugTest - Installs the Test build for the f1 build
installF1Release -- Installs the Release build for flavor f1
installF2Debug - Installs the Debug build for flavor f2
installF2DebugTest - Installs the Test build for the f2 build
installF2Release -- Installs the Release build for flavor f2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you guys don't see the `installDebug` option on running `./gradlew tasks` under the **Install Tasks** section like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/md1id.jpg). Then please set the **ANDROID_HOME** environment variable as follows:

On Linux( Ubuntu)

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/username/Android/Sdk/ # As in my case, yours might be somewhere else
```

To make the above change permanent, pls add this line to your .bashrc in your home directory. (~/.bashrc) and then:

`source ~/.bashrc`

To get the changes in the current shell. Now, you would most likely see the `installDebug` in the Install Tasks when you run `./gradlew InstallDebug`.

Then just connect your device from usb ( [if device not visible for debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30555893/8030107)) and run `./gradlew installDebug`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue.  The symptom is:

> Under the Gradle-Tasks / Install category, there's only 1 task "InstallAll"

My Solution is:

> 1.Install `Android NDK`, using the `SDK-Manager` of Andorid-Studio.
>   2.Make sure the "Android NDK Location" field of the project-settings (File -> Project Structure) is not empty.  It should be something similar to: `/Users/charlie/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle`

After I have the `Android NDK` installed, I can see many other Install-Tasks in Android-Studio now.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle installDebug menu has disppared, manual add Gradle configuration can work!
[image]