# Task 'installDebug' not found in root project 'Android'

Tags: build.gradle

"I'm using command line to build android project but gradlew installDebug command is giving an error. Showing Task 'installDebug' not found in root project 'Android'"

My top-level build.gradle file:-

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My Module-level build.gradle file is:-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.avinash.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Step 1 :

Don't use `react-native run-android`.

#### Step 2 :

If you are using Windows and you don't have the file `gradlew.bat` (but only gradlew), download it [from here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/facebook/react-native/92073770589abc68654e6f1abdd232b45241b181/template/android/gradlew.bat) or copy it from an another react-native project.

#### Step 3 :

In directory /android execute the command `gradlew tasks` or `gradlew.bat tasks` if you are on Windows.

Check the commands that can be used in Install tasks

```
Install tasks
-------------
installDevKernelDebug - Installs the DebugDevKernel build.
installDevKernelDebugAndroidTest - Installs the android (on device) tests for the DevKernelDebug build.
installProdKernelDebug - Installs the DebugProdKernel build.
installProdKernelDebugAndroidTest - Installs the android (on device) tests for the ProdKernelDebug build.
uninstallAll - Uninstall all applications.
uninstallDevKernelDebug - Uninstalls the DebugDevKernel build.
uninstallDevKernelDebugAndroidTest - Uninstalls the android (on device) tests for the DevKernelDebug build.
uninstallDevKernelRelease - Uninstalls the ReleaseDevKernel build.
uninstallProdKernelDebug - Uninstalls the DebugProdKernel build.
uninstallProdKernelDebugAndroidTest - Uninstalls the android (on device) tests for the ProdKernelDebug build.
uninstallProdKernelRelease - Uninstalls the ReleaseProdKernel build.
Use the command gradlew installDevKernelDebug.
```

#### Step 4 :

If you are using react-native, go in the root directory and run `npm start` or `expo start` if you are using expo.
In the browser go to http://localhost:19002 (or the port it says on your console).

Select the local connection and recover the value like
expXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX://127.0.0.1:19000.

Check the file on `.\android\app\src\main\java\host\exp\exponent\generated\DetachBuildConstants.java` and copy the value in `DEVELOPMENT_URL` variable.

#### Step 5 :

Exit Metro Bundler with CTRL+C on the console.

#### Step 6 :

Run `cd android` to enter ./android/ directory

#### Step 7 :

Run `gradlew installDevKernelDebug` or other task you listed on **Step 3**.

I found most of these directions on this thread: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/4097

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the `Android NDK`, can try to install it using the `SDK Manager` of Android-Studio.

For details can refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58987549/1435026