# Adb wont recognise AVD

Tags: android, adb, android-virtual-device

I'm using ADT 22.6.3 on Linux.

I started an emulator like `$ ./emulator -avd API_10_ARM`

But adb wont recognise it:

```
$ adb kill-server
$ adb devices 
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached 

$
```

ADB version:

```
$ adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.31
```

Edit: The emulator is listening on 5554 and 5555:

```
$ netstat -tulpn | grep emul
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5554          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      23236/emulator64-ar
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5555          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      23236/emulator64-ar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A. try `sudo adb kill-server`

followed by `sudo adb devices`

B. try running adb from the `platform-tools` directly

or alternatively, install android-tools-adb using apt-get

Comment: I'm afraid no luck with sudo.

Comment: does the emulator started with eclipse/AVD manager show up? also, do devices connected show up?

Comment: Well now I'm getting `cannot bind 'local:5037'`. I guess I'll have to restart the PC and try again.

Comment: Adb wont recognise emulators started from the AVD. I'll check my phone next.

Comment: Adb **will** recognise my phone.

Comment: try assigning the emulator to some other ports, maybe the ports are blocked. Also, try starting the emulator from eclipse, you can check the console and LogCat for error messages

Comment: OK, trying a different port number (I'm using odd numbers between 5555 and 5585) does not work.

Comment: When starting in eclipse, I get logcat output but I still cannot get adb on the command line to work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721778/adb-no-devices-found did you try these?

Comment: I looked at those suggestions and then I tried running adb from the platform-tools directory and that worked! Thanks. Perhaps this could be considered a duplicate question (it has a duplicate answer at least), or you could modify your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: What I did was add the platform-tools directory to the PATH variable.