# ADB always offline

Tags: android, adb

**My environment**:

**ADB version** : 1.0.26

**SDK platform tools** : 20

I had rooted my **HTC INSPIRE 4G** with *JellyTime ROM (Android 4.2.2)*. 
I tried connecting via USB as well as TCP.

But I am not able to detect the device via adb Console.

What may be the reason for this and how can we solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your drivers are OK you must update your `SDK Tools` and `SDK Platform-Tools`.

Then use `adb kill-server` and `adb devices`, "offline" should be gone.

If it doesn't work you can edit your `android_winusb.inf` adding these lines. (Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17186551/2285184) before do it ;) )

> ; HTC Inspire
>
> %SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0CA2
>
> %CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0CA2&MI_01

Go to device manager and update your driver using this file.

Then use `adb kill-server` and `adb devices`.

Comment: My SDK Tools and SDK Platform-Tools are already updated. Even I used them. adb kill-server ,adb start-server and many of them. But still the situation is same.

Comment: @SanjogShrestha I edited my answer, tell me if it works.

Comment: **
;HTC Inspire 
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0CA2 
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0CA2&MI_01 


[USB_Install]
Include = winusb.inf
Needs   = WINUSB.NT   **                                                I have already modified my android_winusb too. I have left no stones unturned for that.

Answer (score 0):

It's sound like a Driver issue,
Try to download the good one and uptade the previous one, You may have to disable Windows update auto install drivers function.

Don't forget to enable the Debug USB function on your device.

EDIT :

I got the same issue because adb wasn't running in root mode, try to install adbd insecure which grants you root adb access : http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1687590

Comment: Actually after rooting the device only the problem arose. I have installed the drivers as well but the problem is persistent.

Answer (score 0):

Turn debug on phone: Settings - Developer options - USB debugging = ON

Comment: What is your IDE and OS?

Comment: Windows 7 and Eclipse Juno

Comment: Alt-Ctrl-Del -> Task Manager -> Process -> and kill all process 'adb.exe' than restart Eclipse and select your device inside DDMS