# adb devices - No device attached

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

I need to see my Nexus 7 on the adb devices list.
Although I enable the "" USB debugging "" on the device, but when I try to see the "" adb devices "", then no device is attached?

[image]

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/27290476/4385913

Comment: You can mark it as a correct question, and close this question as a answered :)

Comment: what about samsung galaxy s3 mini, same problem

Comment: For now you asked for a Nexus7 and we solved this problem, maybe you can create another question refering **Samsung Galaxy s3 mini** :) I'll search what's the problem with that device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First you have to download [Google USB Driver](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html)
2. Connect your Android-powered device to your computer's USB port.
3. Right-click on `Computer` from your desktop or `Windows Explorer`,
   and select Manage.
4. Select `Devices` in the left pane.
5. Locate and expand `Other` device in the right pane.
6. Right-click the device name and `select Update`
       Driver Software. This will launch the `Hardware Update Wizard`.
7. Select `Browse` my computer for driver software and click `Next`.
       Click `Browse` and locate the `USB driver` folder. (The Google USB
       Driver is located in \extras\google\usb_driver.)
8. Click `Next` to install the driver.

Answer (score 0):

I know that you've already received right answer. But for those who meet the same error I advice to look for "Revoke USB debugging authorizations" in Developers options on your device. Sometimes it really helps! Especially if everything worked fine before in another OS.

Answer (score -1):

Case study (on my WXP SP3... yes I still use it..), phone AllView V2ViperE, Android version 5.1:
If you continue to have no devices attached (although Android Composite ADB Interface is OK in Device Manager.. I mean without the yellow "!"), the root cause could be the adb server.. Workaround: download a new adb release (e.g: http://www.androidro.ro/descarca-si-instaleaza-driveri-adb-pentru-telefoanele-allview/).. I choose V1 Viper S.. unrar and run adb-setup-1.4.2.exe which will create the C:\adb\ directory:

```
C:\adb>dir
Directory of C:\adb
12/11/2016  03:23 PM    <DIR>          .
12/11/2016  03:23 PM    <DIR>          ..
10/19/2014  02:18 AM         1,009,664 adb.exe
10/19/2014  02:18 AM            96,256 AdbWinApi.dll
10/19/2014  02:18 AM            60,928 AdbWinUsbApi.dll
10/19/2014  02:18 AM           196,608 fastboot.exe
               4 File(s)      1,363,456 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   6,116,716,544 bytes free
C:\adb>
```

Now just run:

```
C:\adb>.\adb devices -l
adb server is out of date.  killing...
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached
DQBMWGSC9HT8CQ7D       unauthorized
//V. in this stage allow USB debugging on the phone, then just run again:
C:\adb>.\adb devices -l
List of devices attached
DQBMWGSC9HT8CQ7D       device product:V2_Viper_E model:V2_Viper_E device:V2_Viper_E
C:\adb>.\adb -d shell
shell@V2_Viper_E:/ $
```

Eclipse/LogCat also come alive.. Voila.. Vive la Roumanie.. Now I'm struggling with ndk debugging..