# how to debug on the smartphone Wiko (KITE)

Tags: android, adb, android-debug

how to debug on wiko smart phone (version KITE),android version 4.4.2
I activated the debug option on my phone and  I installed adb driver from:

http://adbdriver.com/upload/AdbDriverInstaller.exe

But without success, my android studio did not detect my phone!

This issue happens only with my phone wiko, I test on other phones like Sony and Samsung and they are detected
I am using Windows 8 as OS.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Is this the only phone you have to test on? Is the issue specific to this phone or has it happened with other phones?

Comment: Have you seen/tried the solutions in : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721778/adb-no-devices-found

Comment: for steps to narrow down your issue read http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/11/adb-device-detection-in-windows.html

Comment: if it happens to be caused by lack of proper driver read http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/11/how-to-make-truly-universal-adb-and.html