# Deploying to Android device not found in Visual Studio

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to deploy an **Apache Cordova** app to an android device that's plugged into the machine. However when attempting to deploy, I receive the following error:

> Unable to deploy to Android device, no attached device was found. If you recently attached a device, you may need to wait a few seconds before it is recognized.

As far as I'm aware, I've enabled all of the developer settings I need in order to deploy to the device. I've tried unplugging and plugging it back in, waiting a few seconds but to no avail.

I've tried changing the connection modes (HTC Sync, Disk Drive ect) however that hasn't made a difference.

The android device I'm trying to deploy to is pretty old (v3.35.61.3), so I've even tried to deploying to a different android device running the latest version of android however the same issue occurs.

This leads me to believe that it's an issue with Visual Studio not picking up any connected android devices. Perhaps I'm missing an install package?

Comment: With your device plugged in run `adb devices` in your CLI to check whether it was recognized

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After smashing my head against a wall for a couple of hours, I managed to get this fixed.

I followed [these instructions](http://www.howtogeek.com/125769/how-to-install-and-use-abd-the-android-debug-bridge-utility/) to install the SDKs for the target device.

There was still an issue where the `abd devices` command was still not showing up with any devices, I installed the [Universal ABD driver](https://plus.google.com/103583939320326217147/posts/BQ5iYJEaaEH) which I found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721778/adb-no-devices-found) question and that worked for me.

---

**EDIT**

Some of you have found that the following can also fix the issue:

1. Turn on the **Developer Options** on the device.
2. Enable **USB Debugging**.

It might be worth trying this first, and if that doesn't work, try what I did.

Comment: I had the same problem and fixed it by Enable USB Debugging on Android device.

Answer (score 5):

I ran in to this problem and I was sure I had everything installed. After some thought I tried to deploy again, and in the developer options on the device I turned usb debugging off and then back on, this got me a prompt to remember my computer's fingerprint. After that everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too (can't reply to the answer because my rep is too low) and I found out that when my phone updates, it turns USB Debugging off.  It's worth the time to check.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my S4. When I turned on the developer options the Enable USB Debugging was turned off. Once I turned that back on the issue was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

First option : Enable **USB DEBUGGING**
Second option : Change your phone cable.