# 'Allow USB debugging' Android 12 Dialog not shown if connected to raspberry pi 4

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, adb

I get the Phone Dialog (rsa fingerprint etc) if connected to my linux laptop and raspberry pi 3b+, **but I don't get it if I connect the phone to the raspberry pi 4**.
The pi4 seems not to be checked for authorization although I see the banner `USB Debugging connected` on the phone's display.
Furthermore `journalctl --dmesg` shows the phone's connected and it's serial number as well.

Yet the phone doesn't ask for allowance and subsequently `adb devices` remains empty on the raspi 4.

I tried multiple usb cables, all usb ports, killing and starting `adb`, re-enabling `Developer options` and `USB debugging` but now am running out of ideas.

I've read and tried all suggestions from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721778/adb-no-devices-found) as well

Comment: Have you set the correct udev rules? https://android.stackexchange.com/a/144967/2241

Comment: @Robert That's the answer. Thank you very much.